# Automatic future date in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

In Word using fields it's possible to have an automatic future date, like next year, that updates whenever the file is opened; is it possible also in PowerPoint 2019? At the moment I found how to insert the current date, but not a future one.

Comment: As J. Mini said, PPT does not currently have such a function. The feasible way is probably through VBA, but there is no direct way

Answer (score 1):

If I may offer a sad and last-ditch solution, [you can embed Word documents in to PowerPoints](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-a-word-document-c926adb3-4aa9-4b13-a5d1-587c6752bda7). If you already have a Word document with the desired behavior, then you just need to embed that.

Sadly, the fact that [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20365647/10319707) has almost 1500 views and no simple answers suggests to me that we can't any better than what I've suggested. You might be able to [do it with macros](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/add-text-and-automatically-updating-future-date-to/bfafdbfa-ce48-48e8-aff3-7ab04035a458?tab=AllReplies#tabs), but they're not simple.